# Comment or answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, pronunciation

I sometimes hesitate using answer or comment. In [this case](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53277/how-to-pronounce-v-sound) I didn't hesitate because I didn't think giving a link was worth an answer. (I suppose my subconscious was reluctant  to see me gain undue upvotes for just giving a link I always keep handy and that it costs me no effort to research.)

After @Anonymous's comment (as a reply to my own comment) should I post my original comment as an answer? Well others have answered but I can see the point in some cases in preferring practical advice on how to improve one's performance rather than a linguistic explanation - however good it is.

And wouldn't writing it as an answer make it more available to others who were looking for help in pronunciation?

Or maybe should there be a wiki where to list tips and links that are not specific to one question? After all the link to the [animated library of the phonetic sounds of American English](http://www.uiowa.edu/~acadtech/phonetics/#) is useful to all questions on American English pronunciation.

Answer (score 5):

An answer that contains a little more than a link is not considered an answer. To be an answer, it should answer the question being asked without redirecting users to another site; the reason is that link rot can happen, and when it happens, what is left is a post containing a not useful link. In this specific case, the link takes you to a page that doesn't directly answer the question; the OP can get the answer clicking on different links found on the linked page.

About a wiki, questions about resources are generally off-topic on EL&U. What you call wiki is a question where nobody gains any reputation (Community Wiki question); its purpose is not anymore to make borderline questions acceptable, and questions asking for resources about pronunciation are borderline questions. The answers to those questions would be possibly infinite; every time a new resource is available, a new answer should be added, or an existing answer should be edited to add it. Every answer would be equally valid, which means that such lists of resources could not be useful to any future reader, who could find references to resources not available anymore.

Comment: The purpose of the Community Wiki has been recently changed. Before, questions asking for lists were acceptable, but made Community Wiki; now, CW questions should be acceptable only if they are acceptable as non CW questions. So far, I have not seen any question that should be make a CW. If once the purpose of CW questions was to lower the reputation needed to edit a post, with proposed edits that is not anymore the reason to make a question CW. The only reason would be not to gain any reputation from the question, or answering the question.